# Transparent background on opening up CS5 on OS X

Tags: macos, photoshop-cs5

When I launch Photoshop CS5 on my iMac, all I see is the Mac's desktop background and the CS5 toolbars. How can I launch Photoshop CS5 so that I get a chequered or plain background as I used to in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can also select *Window - Application Frame* to switch to a more Windows-like UI.

[image]

Comment: Oh, interesting. I've never seen that before. +1 to you.